# Facebook Status Logger Application

Tags: facebook, security, logging

I need to either use or develop a Facebook logger application to track the status updates (or posts) of 100 company employees who are overseas in a sensative country (where each is a friend of my 'dummy' user). The reason is that they may unintentionally post sensative information and compromise our business venture.

I am in the process of trying out ThinkUp ([link](http://thinkupapp.com/docs/index.html)), which seems like overkill but a workable solution. What other secure tools are out there?

Comment: sounds shadier than a 100 year old oak.

Comment: don't judge a book by its cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can consider to write your own app, run that by using the dummy user's credential/toke,
the app can then periodically scan for the friend's status/posts.
A summary email/page can then be formatted.